# LIGHTWEIGHT Java Environment (not JDEE)

Tags: java

Is there a lightweight Java environment for EMACS? I have used JDEE in the past, but it's accumulated a lot of, ahem, features since I used it last, and just trying to set it up has consumed a couple hours.

Comment: On emacs.zeef.com there are alternatives under Java/C# section for your question.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [Meghanada](https://github.com/mopemope/meghanada-emacs). It is light weighted, much easier to setup (compared to JDEE). It is not mature enough, but already supports auto-completion, syntax-checking and runs junit tests. It will also parse maven and gradle projects automatically. The overall experience is smooth enough for small and moderate scale projects. Refactoring support is still in its todo list though.

[Ensime](http://ensime.org) also worth a try. It is pretty good for Scala development, also has limited support for Java. But some rough edges are there.

Comment: If you use `spacemacs` with Emacs, using the `java` layer with `meghanada` as backend downloads the `meghanada` server automatically. It's almost flawless now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-java ,
it uses  `Eclipse JDT Language Server` as backend.

Comment: It has improved dramatically, to the point it's comfortably usable on a 32-bit laptop maxed-out at 2Gb of RAM. The language server installs automatically and detects maven-generated projects without any manual intervention. And it feels as lightweight as `meghanada`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you'd consider it "lightweight," but I've had good luck with [eclim](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim).  It uses eclipse for the heavy lifting, but it also integrates well with eclipse's project management.  It has company integration that works well.

There's a bit to learn, but not a whole lot.  It works well to reduce the pain of working with Java in Emacs to just the pain of working in Java.